# C# - Read from excel sheet and pass variables into function

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm basically looking for some ideas as to the best way of constructing code to read an excel file and create user accounts.

I already have the code to both read the excel file and create the accounts, however I'm unsure as to the best way of passing the data from the excel sheet into the "CreateUser" function.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace INB201_SAMS.Admin
{
    public partial class UploadList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var upload = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload"), "myfilename.xlsx");
            CSVUpload.SaveAs(upload);

            var excelConString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0", upload);

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(excelConString))
            {
                con.Open();

                OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [UserUpload$]", con);

                OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();



            }

            File.Delete(upload);

            Response.Write("Upload Successfull!");

        }



        protected bool CreateUser(string UsersUsername, string UsersPassword)
        {

            try
            {
                MembershipUser newUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(UsersUsername, UsersPassword);
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UsersUsername, "student");
                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageYo.Text = ex.ToString();
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `System.Web.UI.Page` needed. Can't you just use `Page` as you are `using System.Web.UI`

Comment: I'm aware I haven't called CreateUser - I just wrote what I knew

Comment: Are you saying that (new) user account information is in the Excel file, that you're successfully retrieving it, and that now you need to pass it to the CreateUser() method?

Comment: Since you already have a DataReader object, you just need to read the data out of it. Tony722's answer works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something real simple:

```
while(dr.Read()) {
    string user = dr[0].ToString();
    string pass = dr[1].ToString();
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass)) 
       CreateUser(user, pass)
}
dr.Close()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after - Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your username and userpassword are in two column. In that case. you can Read a Specific Column of Excel by its specific headers. This is the discussion of this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/6506b0b1-be8c-40f9-879f-21715bd2792e. Then you can pass the values to the function.

A workaround for this: [go through XML file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371595/Generate-Excel-from-XML-and-Generate-XML-from-Exce) which means convert Excel to XML, and then get data from xml to function.

Comment: Thanks mate - Will post back shortly :)